# Selenium C# No puedo hacer click en un elemento del sub menu

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo el siguiente problema, resulta que estoy utilizando selenium con c# y al realizar un click sobre un sub-menu, se despliega el siguiente error:

> An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException'
>   occurred in AutomatizacionAkzio.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot click on element

Mi código es:

```
Utilitarios.IniciarEnIE(ParametrosEjecucion.RutaDelSitioProd);
PropiedadColeccionDriver.driver.SwitchTo().Frame("0");

Actions action = new Actions(PropiedadColeccionDriver.driver);

List<IWebElement> menu = Utilitarios.ObtieneElementosPorClase("middle");

IWebElement elemento = menu.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text.Equals("CONFIGURADORES"));

action.MoveToElement(elemento).Click().Perform();

string page = PropiedadColeccionDriver.driver.PageSource;

IWebElement frameSubMenu = PropiedadColeccionDriver.driver.FindElement(By.TagName("iframe"));

PropiedadColeccionDriver.driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameSubMenu);

List<IWebElement> subMenu = Utilitarios.ObtieneElementosPorClase("label-cell");

subMenu[3].Click();  //Aquí ocurre el problema
```

El Html de la etiqueta iframe:

```
<div id="scroll-container" style="OVERFLOW: hidden">
<table cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="empty-icon-cell"><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td class="label-cell" nowrap="">GRATIFICACION DE ACCESORIO</td>
<td class="shortcut-cell" nowrap="">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="arrow-cell">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class="empty-icon-cell"><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td class="label-cell" nowrap="">GRATIFICACION RECURRENTE</td>
<td class="shortcut-cell" nowrap="">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="arrow-cell">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class="empty-icon-cell"><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td class="label-cell" nowrap="">GRATIFICACION ONESHOT</td>
<td class="shortcut-cell" nowrap="">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="arrow-cell">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class="empty-icon-cell"><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td class="label-cell" nowrap="">CONFIGURACION DE PROMOCIONES</td>
<td class="shortcut-cell" nowrap="">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="arrow-cell">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class="empty-icon-cell"><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td class="label-cell" nowrap="">CONFIGURACION DE PROMOCIONES AL RUT</td>
<td class="shortcut-cell" nowrap="">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="arrow-cell">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

Html Principal

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content=private http-equiv=cache-control>
<META content=no-cache http-equiv=cache-control>
<META content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv=content-type>
<META content=-1 http-equiv=expires>
<META content=-1 http-equiv=last-modified>
<META content=no-cache http-equiv=pragma><LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="../css/entelpcs.css"><LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="../css/classmenu.css">
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="../js/menu4/poslib.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="../js/menu4/scrollbutton.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="../js/menu4/menu4.js"></SCRIPT>

<STYLE type=text/css>
    body
    {
        border:         0;
        margin:         0;
        overflow:       hidden;
    }
    html
    {
        border:         0;
        overflow:       hidden;
    }
    .menu-bar
    {
        border-bottom:  2px groove;
    }
    p
    {
        font:           Message-Box;
        font:           MessageBox;
        margin:         10px;
    }
    .warning
    {
        color:          red;
    }
    a
    {
        color:          blue;
    }
    textarea
    {
        margin:         10px;
        display:        block;
        width:          auto;
    }
    </STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY leftMargin=0 topMargin=0>

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript> 
    <!-- 
    var message="Copyright©Entel PCS Telecomunicaciones S.A."; 
    function click(e) { 
        if (document.all) { 
            if (event.button == 2) { 
                alert(message); 
                return false; 
            } 
        } 
        if (document.layers)    { 
            if (e.which == 3)   { 
                alert(message); 
                return false; 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    if (document.layers)    { 
        document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN); 
    } 
    document.onmousedown=click; 
    // --> 
    </SCRIPT>

<TABLE id=table1 height=50 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD height=50 background=../images/image015.jpg width=96>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD height=50 background=../images/image016.jpg align=right><B><FONT color=#ffffff size=1 face=Tahoma>SISTEMA PROMOCIONES HOGAR&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<BR>VERSIÓN 1.0.0.0&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</FONT></B> </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" align=left border=0 heigth="30">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD><!--prueba uno  -->

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
            var cssFile = "../css/classmenu.css";
            Menu.prototype.cssFile            = cssFile;
            Menu.prototype.mouseHoverDisabled = false;
            var Temporal;
            var MenuBarra  = new MenuBar();
            var ArrNivelA = new Array();
ArrNivelA[0] = new Array(7);
ArrNivelA[0][0]='1';
ArrNivelA[0][1]='0';
ArrNivelA[0][2]='0';
ArrNivelA[0][3]='0';
ArrNivelA[0][4]='0';
ArrNivelA[0][5]='CONFIGURADORES';
ArrNivelA[0][6]='ruta1';
ArrNivelA[0][7]='';
ArrNivelA[1] = new Array(7);
ArrNivelA[1][0]='2';
ArrNivelA[1][1]='0';
ArrNivelA[1][2]='0';
ArrNivelA[1][3]='0';
ArrNivelA[1][4]='0';
ArrNivelA[1][5]='CONSULTA DE PROMOCIONES';
ArrNivelA[1][6]='ruta2';
ArrNivelA[1][7]='';
ArrNivelA[2] = new Array(7);
ArrNivelA[2][0]='3';
ArrNivelA[2][1]='0';
ArrNivelA[2][2]='0';
ArrNivelA[2][3]='0';
ArrNivelA[2][4]='0';
ArrNivelA[2][5]='MANTENEDOR DE PARAMETROS';
ArrNivelA[2][6]='ruta3';
ArrNivelA[2][7]='';
var ArrNivelB = new Array();
ArrNivelB[0] = new Array(7);
ArrNivelB[0][0]='1';
ArrNivelB[0][1]='1';
ArrNivelB[0][2]='0';
ArrNivelB[0][3]='0';
ArrNivelB[0][4]='0';
ArrNivelB[0][5]='GRATIFICACION DE ACCESORIO';
ArrNivelB[0][6]='ruta4';
ArrNivelB[0][7]='1';
ArrNivelB[1] = new Array(7);
ArrNivelB[1][0]='1';
ArrNivelB[1][1]='2';
ArrNivelB[1][2]='0';
ArrNivelB[1][3]='0';
ArrNivelB[1][4]='0';
ArrNivelB[1][5]='GRATIFICACION RECURRENTE';
ArrNivelB[1][6]='ruta5';
ArrNivelB[1][7]='1';
ArrNivelB[2] = new Array(7);
ArrNivelB[2][0]='1';
ArrNivelB[2][1]='3';
ArrNivelB[2][2]='0';
ArrNivelB[2][3]='0';
ArrNivelB[2][4]='0';
ArrNivelB[2][5]='GRATIFICACION ONESHOT';
ArrNivelB[2][6]='ruta6';
ArrNivelB[2][7]='1';
ArrNivelB[3] = new Array(7);
ArrNivelB[3][0]='1';
ArrNivelB[3][1]='4';
ArrNivelB[3][2]='0';
ArrNivelB[3][3]='0';
ArrNivelB[3][4]='0';
ArrNivelB[3][5]='CONFIGURACION DE PROMOCIONES';
ArrNivelB[3][6]='ruta7';
ArrNivelB[3][7]='1';
ArrNivelB[4] = new Array(7);
ArrNivelB[4][0]='1';
ArrNivelB[4][1]='5';
ArrNivelB[4][2]='0';
ArrNivelB[4][3]='0';
ArrNivelB[4][4]='0';
ArrNivelB[4][5]='CONFIGURACION DE PROMOCIONES AL RUT';
ArrNivelB[4][6]='ruta8';
ArrNivelB[4][7]='1';
ArrNivelB[5] = new Array(7);
ArrNivelB[5][0]='2';
ArrNivelB[5][1]='1';
ArrNivelB[5][2]='0';
ArrNivelB[5][3]='0';
ArrNivelB[5][4]='0';
ArrNivelB[5][5]='CONSULTA PROMOCIONES';
ArrNivelB[5][6]=ruta9';
ArrNivelB[5][7]='1';
ArrNivelB[6] = new Array(7);
ArrNivelB[6][0]='2';
ArrNivelB[6][1]='2';
ArrNivelB[6][2]='0';
ArrNivelB[6][3]='0';
ArrNivelB[6][4]='0';
ArrNivelB[6][5]='CONSULTA PROMOCIONES COMPLETO';
ArrNivelB[6][6]='ruta10';
ArrNivelB[6][7]='1';
ArrNivelB[7] = new Array(7);
ArrNivelB[7][0]='3';
ArrNivelB[7][1]='1';
ArrNivelB[7][2]='0';
ArrNivelB[7][3]='0';
ArrNivelB[7][4]='0';
ArrNivelB[7][5]='MANTENEDOR DE PARAMETROS';
ArrNivelB[7][6]='ruta11;
ArrNivelB[7][7]='1';

            // VARIABLES PARA CREAR NIVELES.
            nContadorNivelA = 3;
            nContadorNivelB = 8;
            nContadorNivelC = 0;
            nContadorNivelD = 0;
            nContadorNivelE = 0;

            var MenuNivelB = new Menu();
            var MenuNivelC = new Menu();
            var MenuNivelD = new Menu();
            var MenuNivelE = new Menu();
            var MarcaC     = 0;
            var MarcaD     = 0;
            var MarcaE     = 0;
            // NIVEL A.
            if (nContadorNivelA > 0)
            {
                for (var a=0; a < ArrNivelA.length; a++)
                {
                    // NIVEL B.
                    if (nContadorNivelB > 0)
                    {
                        MenuNivelB = new Menu();
                        for (var b=0; b < ArrNivelB.length; b++)
                        {
                            MenuNivelC = new Menu();
                            MarcaC     = 0;
                            if (ArrNivelA[a][0] == ArrNivelB[b][0])
                            {
                                // NIVEL C.
                                if (nContadorNivelC > 0)
                                {
                                    for (var c=0; c < ArrNivelC.length; c++)
                                    {
                                        MenuNivelD = new Menu();
                                        MarcaD     = 0;
                                        if ( (ArrNivelA[a][0] == ArrNivelC[c][0]) && (ArrNivelB[b][1] == ArrNivelC[c][1]) )
                                        {
                                            // NIVEL D.
                                            if (nContadorNivelD > 0)
                                            {
                                                for (var d=0; d < ArrNivelD.length; d++)
                                                {
                                                    MenuNivelE = new Menu();
                                                    MarcaE     = 0;
                                                    if ( (ArrNivelA[a][0] == ArrNivelD[d][0]) && (ArrNivelB[b][1] == ArrNivelD[d][1]) && (ArrNivelC[c][2] == ArrNivelD[d][2]) )
                                                    {
                                                        // NIVEL E.
                                                        if (nContadorNivelE > 0)
                                                        {
                                                            for (var e=0; e < ArrNivelE.length; e++)
                                                            {
                                                                if ( (ArrNivelA[a][0] == ArrNivelE[e][0]) && (ArrNivelB[b][1] == ArrNivelE[e][1]) && (ArrNivelC[c][2] == ArrNivelE[e][2]) && (ArrNivelD[d][3] == ArrNivelE[e][3]) )
                                                                {
                                                                    MenuNivelE.add(Temporal = new MenuItem( ArrNivelE[e][5] , ArrNivelE[e][6] ));
                                                                    Temporal.target = ArrNivelE[e][7];
                                                                    MarcaE++;
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        MarcaD++;
                                                        if (MarcaE == 0)
                                                        {
                                                            MenuNivelD.add(Temporal = new MenuItem( ArrNivelD[d][5] , ArrNivelD[d][6] ));

                                Temporal.target = ArrNivelD[d][7];
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            MenuNivelD.add( Temporal = new MenuItem( ArrNivelD[d][5], null, null, MenuNivelE ) );
                                                            Temporal.target = ArrNivelD[d][7];
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            MarcaC++;
                                            if (MarcaD == 0)
                                            {
                                                MenuNivelC.add(Temporal = new MenuItem( ArrNivelC[c][5] , ArrNivelC[c][6] ));
                                                Temporal.target = ArrNivelC[c][7];
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                MenuNivelC.add( Temporal = new MenuItem( ArrNivelC[c][5], null, null, MenuNivelD ) );
                                                Temporal.target = ArrNivelC[c][7];
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                if (MarcaC == 0)
                                {
                                    MenuNivelB.add( Temporal = new MenuItem( ArrNivelB[b][5], ArrNivelB[b][6] ) );
                                    Temporal.target = ArrNivelB[b][7];
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    MenuNivelB.add( Temporal = new MenuItem( ArrNivelB[b][5], null, null, MenuNivelC ) );
                                    Temporal.target = ArrNivelB[b][7];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // NIVEL A.
                    MenuBarra.add(Temporal = new MenuButton( ArrNivelA[a][5], MenuNivelB ) );
                }
                Temporal.mnemonic = a;
            }
            MenuBarra.write();
            </SCRIPT>

<DIV id=-menu-cache-5 class=menu-bar unselectable="on"><SPAN class="menu-button active" unselectable="on"><SPAN class=left unselectable="on"></SPAN><SPAN class=middle unselectable="on">CONFIGURADORES</SPAN><SPAN class=right unselectable="on"></SPAN></SPAN><SPAN class="menu-button " unselectable="on"><SPAN class=left unselectable="on"></SPAN><SPAN class=middle unselectable="on">CONSULTA DE PROMOCIONES</SPAN><SPAN class=right unselectable="on"></SPAN></SPAN><SPAN class="menu-button " unselectable="on"><SPAN class=left unselectable="on"></SPAN><SPAN class=middle unselectable="on">MANTENEDOR DE PARAMETROS</SPAN><SPAN class=right unselectable="on"></SPAN></SPAN></DIV></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><IFRAME style="HEIGHT: 10px; WIDTH: 10px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: -100px; TOP: -100px; VISIBILITY: hidden" frameBorder=0></IFRAME></BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Hola Felipe bienvenido, Mira [ask] y [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad. Además deberías realizar el [tour] para entender mejor como funciona el sitio.

Comment: gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: No ve nada de malo con su pregunta

Comment: Felipe, no veo la clase `middle` ni el texto `CONFIGURADORES` en el HTML de tu pregunta

Comment: La estructura del html es la siguiente: posee dos frame don id 0 y 1 la clase que mencionas con el texto esta dentro del frame 0, pero resulta que dentro de este frame, posee un iframe. html ya adjuntado

Comment: Deberias de editar tu pregunta con todo el HTML.  Tambien seria bueno que indiques en que linea ocurre el error.

Comment: Mencionaste que este es un submenu.  El texto `GRATIFICACION ONESHOT` esta visible cuando tratas de hacer click?

Comment: no, el texto no esta visible, al igual que todos los elementos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            subMenu[3].SendKeys(Keys.Down);

            subMenu[3].SendKeys(Keys.Down);

            subMenu[3].SendKeys(Keys.Down);

            subMenu[3].SendKeys(Keys.Down);

            subMenu[3].SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```